# SML Program for Comparing Time Stamp

Tags: sml

I am doing an exercise in which two time stamps are given, and I have to find which is large. This program is written in SML. So I come up with this program...

```
val record1 = {hour = 11, min = 45, f = "PM"};    
val record2 = {hour = 2,min = 13,f = "AM"};    
fun timerrecord(record1,record2)=     
if (#f record1 = "PM") andalso (#f record2="AM") then "t1 comes First"    
else if(#f record1 = "AM") andalso (#f record1="PM") then "t2 comes First"     
else if (#hour record1 > #hour record1) then "t1 comes First"    
else if (#hour record1 < #hour record1) then "t2 comes First"    
else if (#min record1 > #min record1) then "t1 comes First"    
else "t2 comes First";
```

The problem is when I write it without the function, it gives the correct result but when I put code in that function (as given above) it gives an error...UNRESOLVED FLEX RECORD.

t1,t2  and record1,record2 are timestamps.

I am new to SML, so any help would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

As user987339 said, you can put in type annotations to resolve the types. But the common way to do this in ML is not to use record selectors `#label` in the first place, but to rely on pattern matching, which implies the types:

```
fun timerRecord({hour = h1, min = m1, f = f1}, {hour = h2, min = m2, f = f2}) =     
    if f1 = "PM" andalso f2 = "AM" then "t1 comes first"    
    else if f1 = "AM" andalso f2 = "PM" then "t2 comes first"     
    else if h1 > h2 then "t2 comes first"    
    else if h1 < h2 then "t1 comes first"    
    else if m1 > m2 then "t2 comes first"    
    else "t1 comes first"
```

(Fixed a couple of cases.)

Answer (score 1):

You have to define record type in order to compile this function. So add:

```
type recc = {hour:int, min:int, f:string};
```

and change your function signature to:

```
fun timerrecord(record1:recc,record2:recc)=
```

Or you can do it a bit "dirty", just by changing function signature to:

```
fun timerrecord(record1:{hour:int, min:int, f:string},record2:{hour:int, min:int, f:string})=
```

Depends how DRY you are :-)

PS: Find what DRY means.